# Coroutine doesn't work when trying to instantiate a destroyed object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been using coroutines for a while so I'm not quite sure why this small piece of code does not work. I destroy an object on collision and I am trying to make it respawn after a number of seconds. I have tried to use setActive(false) but I get an error saying that my coroutine in my other script (that is linked to the one below) does not work.

The debugging that I have in the script below also doesn't even show up in my console at all. Is there something that I am missing?

```
public class SpeedBoost : MonoBehaviour
{

    public PlayerMovement movement;

    public GameObject speedBoost;

    void SpawnObject()
    {
        GameObject newObject = Instantiate(speedBoost);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            movement.SpeedBoost();

            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            StartCoroutine(RespawnSpeedBoost());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RespawnSpeedBoost()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        Instantiate(speedBoost, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Debug.Log("Speed boost respawned");
    }
}
```

I have tried to instantiate to the specific game objects rotation as well as just the standard transform.rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script is attached to the GameObject and it gets destroyed then the script is not available. What you could do is something like this.

```
public class SpeedBoost : MonoBehaviour
{

public PlayerMovement movement;

public GameObject speedBoost;

void SpawnObject()
{
    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(speedBoost);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        movement.SpeedBoost();
        StartCoroutine(RespawnSpeedBoost());
    }
}

IEnumerator RespawnSpeedBoost()
{
    speedBoost.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    speedBoost.SetActive(true);
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried a solution similar to this (and also copied yours), but for some reason the SetActive(true) line doesn't work, even when I adjust the timer from 10 seconds to something lower.

Comment: Is the SpeedBoost script attached to a GameObject or is it just referencing it?

Comment: The SpeedBoost script is attached to the speedBoost gameObject

Comment: I thought that the script was not attached my apologies. Since we are Setting it not active then the SetActive(true) code isnt executing. What you can try is create an empty GameObject as a placeholder for your speedBoost gameObject and then attach the script to the empty GameObject and reference speedBoost.

Comment: I attempted that just now and unfortunately the coroutine doesn't begin at all and there's no speed boost effect anymore, and the setActive(true) & (false) don't work either when I use a placeholder empty object (basically it's as if the whole speed boost script/coroutine don't exist despite me having them referenced in the inspector). Everything in your code works, but I can see in runtime that the object continues to permanently sit there, inactive.

Comment: You probably have to transfer the collider from your speedBoost GameObject to the Empty one for it to work.

Comment: Yeah that works, I'm not sure how I missed adding the collider in. Thanks for the repeated help I appreciate it